# Post Per Page For Portfolio

Tags: posts

I am working on listing some working portfolio. I want to list a certain amount and I was reading the post_per_page can do that.

I have the following query, just trying to figure out where I can add the post par page code. I'm pretty new at php and wordpress. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'nopaging' => true,
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'orderby' => array('menu_order' => 'ASC', 'ID' => 'ASC')
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
get_template_part('loop', 'portfolio');
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Do not use `$wp_query` as your query variable. `$wp_query` holds the main query object, so what you are doing is breaking the main query object for that specific page. Rather use something like `$q`, `$query` or `$my_query`

Answer (score 0):

Yes "posts_per_page" can change the number of posts shown.
Where can you add it to your code?
You can add this parameter to your $args variable.

To add it to your $args variable you can do this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio', 
    'posts_per_page' => 12
);
```

"12" is the number of posts per page that will be shown. Change this whatever number you want.

You can read more about "posts_per_page" [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help but unfortunately for some reason it is listing all the items of my work portfolio theme and not the number I want. The code I provided is for the front page:

http://www.cyberjunkiesinteractive.com/